# Changing the size and position of widgets according to window size in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've been recently trying to use the library Kivy to make applications that will go onto different devices. Each app is known to resize their elements on-screen according to window size and elements having the same definitions. Since I'm pretty new to the world of Kivy, I was wondering how such a thing can be done.

For example:

This is a resolution of 1000x750
[image]

and this is the resolution of 500x350

[image]

Notice how the text resizes with the image.

Anything would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In kivy most of widgets have an argument called `size_hint` which as the name suggests sets size of widget according to screen size. It takes value from `0 to 1`. A value of 0.5 basically means half of screen. You can use `size_hint_x` and `size_hint_y` to define size along x and y axis or together you can use `size_hint = (0.5,0.5)`. Also, if in some cases when you couldn't use size_hint then you can you `Window.size` to get the screen size of the device as a tuple. Assume you want to make something with size 50% of both x and y. Then you can set `size = (Window.size[0]*0.5, Windows.size[1]*0.5)` Window.size[0] is basically length along x-axis and Window.size[1] along y axis

Comment: Thank you so much but how could I position widgets according to a value of ```0 to 1``` like a pos_hint or something similar

Comment: Ya you can use pos_hint for that

Comment: If you found it helpful then please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple,when inserting the size of your widget in the kv file,u will need to divide it by 2 or any number depending on the size you want your widget to be.

Example
Button:
text:"example"
Size_hint:self.width/2,self.height/2
Pos_hint:self.width/2,self.height/2

With the Pos divided by 2, it set the widget to the center and with size_hint = to the size of the window divided by 2 or any number.the size of the widget can be changed due to the change in the window.

It also works for font_size.